# android youtube gallery look

Tags: android, youtube, gallery

Does someone knows how to implement something similar to honeycomb youtube gallery look? I have seen these links:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx?display=Print

but I don't know what transformations do I have to do to the object to be able to get that rounded look. Because using the code from the examples above, does not provide transformations to the objects (items) inside the gallery. I read somewhere that this can be done using OpenGl, but I was wandering if it could be somehow avoided. If someone has ANY idea, please share it with me. I really want to implement this. Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using renderscript. there is an example CarouselExample (http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=) that can me modified, but it takes a lot of work to get to learn renderscript so you can understand the code completely and start using it. But this is the way to go.